# How to perform hide and show buttons in listview items without removing DOM in angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I need to perform hide and show buttons in listview items programatically based on the condition.

Below I have tried *ngif condition. Its removing DOM entirely.So it shows `secondVisible` layout buttons entirely.

**html file:**

```
// inside listview ng-template :

 <Button *ngIf="firstVisible" row="0" col="2" text="First"> </Button>

 <StackLayout *ngIf="secondVisible" row="0" col="2">
    <Button text="second" > </Button>
    <Button text="group"  </Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

**ts file:**

```
  if(avail == true){

            this.firstVisible = true;
            this.secondVisible = false;

           } else {

            this.firstVisible = false;
            this.secondVisible = true;

           }
```

is there any other way to perform hide and show button programatically without removing DOM in listview except *ngif condition.

Comment: You can use [hidden] attribute

Comment: `ngclass` is what can be of good help too along with `hidden`

Comment: @RahulSingh can you please post answer.

Comment: @Steve updated a answer hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `[hidden]` attribute. It will keep the element in the dom.

```
 <Button [hidden]="!firstVisible" row="0" col="2" text="First"> </Button>

 <StackLayout [hidden]="!secondVisible" row="0" col="2">
    <Button text="second" > </Button>
    <Button text="group"  </Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

Comment: there isnt a DOM in nativescript

Comment: Programatically I have to use firstVisible =true and false for hide and show?

Comment: Yes, but i'll change the code to better suit your variable names

Comment: Set your firstVisible and secondVisible  to true in yoir code, and also, when does your if else condition run?

Comment: Then my code is correct, it should work, test it again maybe you did a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button [hidden]="firstVisible" row="0" col="2" text="First"> </Button>
```

Using the hidden property will hide it from the DOM and not delete it entirely, if you want a show use:

```
<Button [hidden]="!firstVisible" row="0" col="2" text="First"> </Button>
```

https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-show explains it more in detail

Answer (score 0):

A plunker i created for this problem .[LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/eNXveYocD76o6p2RA5Vp?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div (click) = "show = !show">
      Book
      <div [ngClass]="(show)?'hide-it':'show-it'"> Details</div>
    </div>

    <div (click) = "show = !show">
      BookS
      <div [ngClass]="(show)?'hide-it':'show-it'"> Detailsss</div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  show:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular 2 Ng Class';
    this.show = "true";
   }
  logout(){
    this.show = "false";
  }

}
```

**CSS**

```
.show-it {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hide-it {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.i will check and let you know.

Comment: Why make is t complex when we have `[hidden]` ?

Comment: @Faisal i mentioned in the question comment either go with ngclass or hidden its own choice , with class you have more flexiblity of adding multiple things in a single statement

Comment: Yes, but in this specific case, i'll prefer using `[hidden]` since we only need to hide and element while also keeping it in dom.

Comment: @Steve can you check the plunker link i mentioned in the answer it works over there though ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I saw that. You are using this clickable `<div (click) = "show = !show">`  to show and hide the view. In my requirement I dont need this clickable event. Directly when coming inside to that page I need to perform hide and show for the particular buttons

Comment: instead of that just make that show in `ngONInit` true or false that will do the job easily. so instead of that the show can be a component var and can be populated made true or false on init. hope you get it.

Comment: @RahulSingh i did that.but it removes dom entirely.so last item value gets displayed in all list items

Comment: But in the plunker you can see it there in dom but hidden. I am not sure what is that not working

Answer (score 0):

I would just use *ngIf with an  for the else block.
The *ngIf would reffer to a variable like isVisible and on the buttonClick you just swap the boolean.
Angular itselfs chnages the view then if you did not mofidied some strange things for the changeDetection ;)